# prove that the group of symmetry's of tetrahedron in $R^{3}$ Isomorphic to $S_4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

prove that the group of symmetry's of tetrahedron in $R^{3}$ Isomorphic to $S_4$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Show that an isometry of the tetrahedron must permute the vertices of the tetrahedron. Show that every permutation of the vertices of a tetrahedron induces exactly one isometry.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use the fact that $S_{4}$ is generated by $(1,2)$ and $(2,3,4)$. Now find two symmetries that induce those two permutations on the vertices.